# Problem with printing copy constructor OOP

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

Having trouble with the printing  copy constructors elements from  Arr s to Arr s1 , also having troubles with << operator it doesn't work, please help cuz I am not pro just a student.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Arr {
private:
    int size;
    int *arr;
public:
  Arr(int size,int *arr) {
      this->size = size;
      this->arr = new int [size];
      for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i) {
         this->arr[i] = arr[i];

      }
  }

    ~Arr() {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    Arr(const Arr &x) {
        this->size = x.size;
        this->arr = new int[x.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size; ++i) {
            this->arr = x.arr;
        }
    }

    Arr() : size(0),arr(0) {}

    Arr(Arr &&x) {
        this->size = x.size;
        this->arr = new int[x.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size; ++i) {
            this->arr = x.arr;
        }
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Arr &t) {
        out << t.size;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size; i++) {
            out << t.arr[i];
        }
        return out;

    }


    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Arr &t) {
        in >> t.size;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size; ++i) {
            in >> t.arr[i];
        }
        return in;
    }



};

int main() {
    int size = 3;
    int arr [] = {1,2,3};
 Arr s1(size,arr);
  cin << s1;
  cout<<s1;
  Arr s(s1);
  cout<<s; // not working at all

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ It seems you mean this->arr[ i ] = x.arr[ i ]; instead of this->arr = x.arr; in the copy constructor And in the move constructor there is no need to allocate a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing

```
this->arr = x.arr;
```

in the copy constructor, rather than

```
this->arr[i] = x.arr[i];
```

That is, currently your code is copying the array pointer, not the elements of the array.

When you're debugging, first look over your code to make sure each part is doing what you want it to do and that you didn't make a typo like this. Then, if you don't find the problem, you can use a debugger like `gdb` to step through your code and monitor the values of the variables to make sure your program is doing what you'd like.